# Windows 8.1 Dual Boot Cannot resize Windows Partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, hard-drive, gparted

My partition scheme I'm making gives Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 80GB each, currently Windows is still hogging 400GB and I'm trying to resize it to 177GB for now.
Tried Windows default partition manager, it could only shrink it 50GB. Defragmented, got an additional 20GB or so. Installed Ubuntu on this 70GB partition and ran GParted to further shrink Windows and no such luck. I get this:

```
GParted 0.18.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 2.3
Shrink /dev/sda4 from 376.82 GiB to 199.71 GiB  00:17:14    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda4  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda4
start: 1697792
end: 791945215
size: 790247424 (376.82 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda4 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:26    ( SUCCESS )

ntfsresize -i -f -v /dev/sda4

ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda4
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 404606677504 bytes (404607 MB)
Current device size: 404606681088 bytes (404607 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use : 200652 MB (49.6%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
Estimating smallest shrunken size supported ...
File feature Last used at By inode
Multi-Record : 401999 MB 1136511
$MFTMirr : 1 MB 1
Compressed : 394065 MB 15450
Sparse : 153807 MB 1761
Ordinary : 404554 MB 2470
You might resize at 200651960320 bytes or 200652 MB (freeing 203955 MB).
Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
shrink file system  00:16:48    ( ERROR )

run simulation  00:16:48    ( ERROR )

ntfsresize --force --force -s 214441132032 --no-action /dev/sda4

ntfsresize v2013.1.13AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda4
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 404606677504 bytes (404607 MB)
Current device size: 404606681088 bytes (404607 MB)
New volume size : 214441128448 bytes (214442 MB)
Checking filesystem consistency ...
100.00 percent completed
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use : 200652 MB (49.6%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
Needed relocations : 15455457 (63306 MB)
Schedule chkdsk for NTFS consistency check at Windows boot time ...
Resetting $LogFile ... (this might take a while)
Relocating needed data ...
100.00 percent completed
allocated extent inode 16
allocated extent inode 16
allocated extent inode 16
allocated extent inode 16
allocated extent inode 16
allocated extent inode 16
allocated extent inode 16
Non-positive free clusters (0)!
Non-positive free clusters (0)!
Non-positive free clusters (0)!
Non-positive free clusters (0)!
Non-positive free clusters (0)!
Updating $BadClust file ...
Updating $Bitmap file ...
ERROR(5): Could not map attribute 0x80 in inode 747981: Input/output error
```

========================================

Any way to get around these 'unmovable files' Windows is putting in my way?
Thanks to everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone with this problem sees this, this solution worked for me:

- Disable pagefile swap
- Disable system recovery
- Disable system protection
  Then defragment and try again, it should work this time.
  These settings allow Windoze to move protected system files it couldn't before.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe from windows, I don't recall the software exactly, but there are a few free ones out there that can let you increase and decrease C drive with no problem by moving around these file.

Comment: I'll ask my friend, and get back to you abou that software

Comment: https://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/

^I think this is it, not completely sure, but give it a shot :P